# Ionic 2 multiple files upload

Tags: ionic2

I am using cordva-camera and successfully figured out to work with it. The problem is that I can send multiple images across my other form variables only if they are base64 encoded.

So my question is how to POST multiple images and other form fields with http.post using Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI ? How to post using native path the images?

Comment: how about sending files one by one.in return get the path or id etc. then post your form with images values.

Comment: well this can be done in worst case scenario, but wondering if I can avoid this and just post images all in one in a single form along with other form values, like we normally do in web apps

Comment: you could try [imagepicker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/image-picker/)

Comment: why worst case! at least you can assure that your files uploaded. of course scenario depend on many things.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform images into Blob Object by using resolveLocalFilesystemUrl which in File plugin. Then put Blob Object into a FormData and upload it. I solved my problem as same as yours by [this article](http://www.longdw.com/ionic2-imagepicker-multiple-file-upload/) and [this](https://golb.hplar.ch/p/Uploading-pictures-from-Ionic-2-to-Spring-Boot).